# pip install into virtualenv from github using -e option fails to add package to python path

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I am trying to install a package from my github in "editable"  (-e) mode to be able to easily work on the repository whilst using it.

However it is causing problems because its not available in the python path after I install it.

With a fresh, clean virtualenv "publisher" created and activated, I run the following:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/roberts81/easy-thumbnails.git#egg=easy_thumbnails
Obtaining easy-thumbnails from git+https://github.com/roberts81/easy-thumbnails.git#egg=easy_thumbnails
  Cloning https://github.com/roberts81/easy-thumbnails.git to /Users/ben/Envs/publisher/src/easy-thumbnails
  Running setup.py egg_info for package easy-thumbnails

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Installing collected packages: easy-thumbnails
  Running setup.py develop for easy-thumbnails

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    Creating /Users/ben/Envs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-thumbnails.egg-link (link to .)
    Adding easy-thumbnails 1.2 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /Users/ben/Envs/publisher/src/easy-thumbnails
Successfully installed easy-thumbnails
Cleaning up...
```

Then if I run python (still in my virtualenv) and try to import anything from that package, It fails.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import easy_thumbnails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named easy_thumbnails
>>>
```

If I install it without the -e option, everything works dandy. I get the same effect (i.e. they aren't on the python path after installing them) with other repo's, e.g. `pip install -e git+http://github.com/django/django.git@stable/1.5.x#egg=django` .  So what gives?

One thing I'm noticing is that it doesn't seem to be actually updating the easy-install.pth file even though it says it is... something odd going on here.

But if i run it (the pip install... command) with sudo, it works! Also I can install the package globally (outside the virtualenv, with sudo of course) and that works.

Versions:

pip==1.2.1
virtualenv==1.8.4
virtualenvwrapper==3.6 
python==2.7.2
Mac OSX 10.8.2

Comment: Looking at it, it says "Adding easy-thumbnails 1.2 to easy-install.pth file" ... but I don't see anything referencing easy-thumbnails in the .pth file.  What on earth is going on?  (And I swear this used to work just fine)

Comment: Tried uninstalling & reinstalling pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by removing my virtualenv, recreating it, activating it, and then (before doing anything else) updating pip and setuptools in the environment. Start by opening a new terminal window (to make sure the virtual env is not activated) and navigate to the directory above where your virtualenv lives. Then do:

```
rm -rf env
virtualenv env
. env/bin/activate
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

After this I was able to install the package from GitHub (using `pip`) and was able to import it in python.

Answer (score 2):

Working for me with pip 1.2.1 and virtualenv 1.8.4:

```
$ virtualenv -p python2.7 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.

$ source venv/bin/activate

$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/roberts81/easy-thumbnails.git#egg=easy_thumbnails
Obtaining easy-thumbnails from git+https://github.com/roberts81/easy-thumbnails.git#egg=easy_thumbnails
  Cloning https://github.com/roberts81/easy-thumbnails.git to ./venv/src/easy-thumbnails
  Running setup.py egg_info for package easy-thumbnails

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Installing collected packages: easy-thumbnails
  Running setup.py develop for easy-thumbnails

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    Creating /Users/jterrace/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-thumbnails.egg-link (link to .)
    Adding easy-thumbnails 1.2 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /Users/jterrace/test/venv/src/easy-thumbnails
Successfully installed easy-thumbnails
Cleaning up...

$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov 12 2012, 09:50:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import easy_thumbnails
>>> easy_thumbnails.VERSION
'1.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might seem silly now since the question has been answered, and this addresses a different issue -- but this was the solution for me when I got this error. (I'm hoping this will help others)

Make sure that you have a `__init__.py` file in place.  The structure should resemble this:

```
/myprojectname
  /myprojectname
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
  setup.py
```

Then run "`pip install -e .`" from within the top level `myprojectname` folder, everything works. I forgot the `__init__.py` in my case, and forgot that this is a possible cause for that message.

Answer (score 0):

Although it addresses a different issue, following [this Mac OSX 10.8-specific thread](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issue/158/installing-virtualenvwrapper-on-on-osx-108) to its conclusion seemed to solve the problem for me.

Specifically, I installed distribute not using pip:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python distribute_setup.py
```

Then I added `export VIRTUALENV_DISTRIBUTE=1` to my ~/.bashrc file and restarted my terminals.

I uninstalled and reinstalled virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper just to be safe.

Then I destroyed my old virtual env's and recreated them.  For whatever reason, fixing up virtualenv to use and install distribute fixes the problem. Wacky.

Comment: Is there a bug report somewhere for this behavior?

Comment: Distribute is [now deprecated](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6.49) - better to use setuptools instead.  Dan Tenenbaum's answer seems more likely to work these days and is what I've done previously on systems with old versions of pip and setuptools: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38404769/992887